# DBConnection to connect to both SQLite and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm looking for, or attempting to write, a connection class that needs to be able to connect to both a SQLite and MySQL databases.  The company I work for uses both of these, and they are so invested, they don't want to switch to only one.  So, I need to either write a DBConnection that will connect to both, or find a framework that does so.  Right now, I wrote my own (in C#) that has some overloaded connection and query functions that will work with the appropriate database based upon parameters passed.  But I'd like it to be as generic as possible, being able to connect and query either SQL-type database, without having a bunch of overloaded functions.  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Are you looking for something that generates the queries too? or do you already have per-vendor queries?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using NHibernate or Entity Framework. You will get much more from an ORM than just being database agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a Framework or library to do this, you should look at [EnterpriseLibary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx).

[Link to CodePlex site](http://entlib.codeplex.com/)